# Passport.js Session Invalidates On Its Own

Tags: javascript, sails.js, passport.js

We have two Sails.js applications using Angular on the front end, `App A` and `App B`, that both authenticate using Passport and OpenID Connect. They both work great independently of the other.

We are now trying to send people from `App A` to `App B`, and when doing that set session variables in `App B`. That actually works fine. The issue is that after doing that, the session in `App A` is invalidated and none of the calls in `App A` work until a refresh is done.

The action that sends us from `App A` to `App B` is a simple link, an `a` tag with an `href` that sends them to the new app. It doesn't seem like it should affect the session at all. Has anyone had any issues like this before? What is the next step to check?

Cookies in the browser were unchanged; just the session on the server was altered.

Comment: Are the two apps on different domains?  Or just different ports?  Cookies don't care about ports, so if you have two apps on the same domain but different ports then they'll end up sharing a cookie.

Comment: Oh okay...yes they're on different ports locally, but both on localhost. In Production and Testing they'll be on different domains.

Comment: So even though this error is because of the session on the server being altered, it could be because they're both on localhost but different ports?

Comment: That'd be my strong guess.  The two sites are sharing one cookie and thus one slot in the session store.  You can test this pretty easily by starting both servers locally and viewing one on http://127.0.0.1 and the other on http://localhost.  If the problem goes away, there you have it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so this doesn't go unanswered: it seems very likely that the issue here is that two apps are being lifted on different ports, but with the same domain (`localhost`).  Because cookies are assigned to *domains* regardless of port, the two apps are both receiving the same cookie from the browser, and thus are sharing a slot in the session store.  When one app changes something in the session, the other app is affected since they share a session.

Since the OP states that in production the two apps will be on different domains, this is really just a problem in development.  There are a few different ways to work around this problem:

1. View one of the apps in an incognito window (or "private browsing", or whatever your particular browser calls it).  This way it will get its own cookie regardless of domain.
2. View one of the apps using `http://localhost`, and the other using `http:/127.0.0.1`.  Different domains, different cookies.
3. Add `app1.localhost` and `app2.localhost` entries to your `/etc/hosts` file (or Windows equivalent), and use those domains when browsing.

Comment: This was the issue. Sorry for taking so long to get back and accept the answer! As soon as we deployed to testing, the issue stopped popping up, and so we are using the workarounds you mentioned above.